# Is scraping Google+ pages/comments/notifications via cURL legal?

Tags: google-plus

The limitations of the Google+ API have just put a hold on a little project I am working on.

I can achieve what I need with a basic cURL script (login to Google+ Page, scrape page, parse data) but I was just wondering if this is allowed?

(yes the script will break whenever they update G+, I can live with that)

A search on "are you allowed to login to google with curl" produces lots of results. So it seems lots of people are doing it, just wondering if anyone knows if it is "really" allowed?

Comment: Of course it is illegal but so is batman ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a legal attorney, always seek advice from law professionals.

However my take on this is that it is legal. Nothing restricts you from crawling websites and performing datamining without wasting the resources of the server (Such as DDOS) and without using any illegal means to attain this information such as exploiting the server software or using some vulnerability that might expose the user data.

If this information is **publicly** available online it belongs to the Public Domain, and as long as you are not selling it, it can be considered fair use.

On the other hand you are violating an awful lot of user agreements.